# Refer to this member as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Say I have a template function that takes a datastructure and, amongst other things, performs an operation on one of its members. For example:

```cpp
template<typename T, int T::*member>
void example(T& t)
{
   t->*member++;
}
```

Now I want to use this function, but in certain cases the member is the object itself. So in the example above, I want to pass an `int` as an argument.

```cpp
int my_value;
example<int, ???>(my_value);
```

Is this possible? What would I put in place of the ???.

I know I can do this by creating a wrapper type that contains nothing but an int, but I'm wondering if it is possible to do this without it. I also know I could create a second copy of the function that doesn't assume the member relationship, but I'd prefer to keep this DRY. Lastly, I need the member relationship as the real function operates on an iterator of T, of which the type cannot be changed.

Comment: The easiest way to do that is to provide an overloaded implementation of `example`.

Comment: Yeah, but that would require making a copy of `example`, no? I'd like to avoid that...

Comment: Then use [a functor](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5ce5978494eb227)